# How do I find the potential energy lost by a ball bearing moving away from a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential-energy

I am carrying out a physics project over the next few weeks and am looking at the [Gaussian gun.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaI9iq5asOE) I'm sure most are familiar with it, but if not it is the experiment where you roll a ball bearing into some magnets and the ball bearing on the other side fires out much faster.

I am looking at different variables and how it effects the speed of the fired ball as soon as it leaves the magnet, but to find this I am looking at the speed further away, using a light gate, and then using energy transfers to find the initial speed of the ball.

My dilemma is I dont know how to find the potential energy gained as the ball bearing moves away from the magnet as all the equations I find all use current, but the magnet isn't an electromagnet. I do have access to a hall probe to find the magnetic field strength at various different points but I'm not sure how to convert this to potential energy. So I am asking if there is an equation to link magnetic field strength to magnetic potential energy of a magnet, **not an electromagnet**, and if so what is it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  I've edited your question to include a demo video of the apparatus you're talking about, since I don't think everyone will be familiar with it.

Comment: Here's a simple model of the process. https://physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/lin_accel.pdf However, you will likely find it overestimates the kinetic energy of the final ball. Beware, it is in cgs units.

Answer (score 1):

A magnetic dipole with moment $\vec \mu$ has an interaction energy with the field

$$
U = -\vec\mu\cdot\vec B
$$

That is, a constant-magnitude magnetic moment can release energy by rotating to align with with the field direction.  An already-aligned magnetic moment can release energy by moving from a weak-field region to a strong-field region.  A strongly-polarizable material like iron can also release energy by letting its moment $\vec\mu$ evolve to be more strongly parallel to $\vec B$.

In the setup shown in your video, each stage of the gun is

```
(B)  [M](B)(B)
     to
  (B)[M](B)          (B)
```

That is, the incident bearing on the left is allowed to reach the strong-field region closest to the permanent magnet. The ejected bearing on the right leaves the weak-field region which is further from the magnet.  So even in the approximation that your ball bearings have constant moment $\vec\mu$, the gun is transferring momentum from strong-field regions to weak-field regions.

Your steel ball bearings have varying $\vec\mu$, which is roughly proportional to $\vec B$ but has some amount of hysteresis, and which also rotates as the bearing rolls.
You’re going to have a complicated time reconstructing the initial energy from the final energy.

Comment: I'm not saying it is very accurate, but there *is* a simple model of this process.

Comment: Having skimmed [your link](https://physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/lin_accel.pdf), my guess is that the effort-to-accuracy ratio is probably not very good. It'd be fun to test, but you'd definitely want to know up front what it is that you're testing.

Comment: It empirically works to factor of two. I think the deficiencies are in the dipole approximation and some energy loss in the contacts.